# Fail when combining ggplots with plots produced from another package: why and how to succeed?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

I want to combine *two ggplots* with *two calibration plots* made in `riskRegression`.

I tried many approaches, e.g. `par(mfrow)` *(see below)*, but failed. I reckon there must be a way to combine `ggplots` with other plots in a `par(mfrow=c(2,2))`-manner.

**Question:** why is this approach invalid, and how can it be fixed?

Data sample `o` can be found below.

I use

```
library(riskRegression)
library(survival)
library(tidyverse)
```

First produce the calibration

```
i <- Score(list("WHO w/o TERT" = coxph(Surv(event.tid, event==1) ~ WHO, data=o, x=T, y=T), 
                "WHO +TERT   " = coxph(Surv(event.tid, event==1) ~ WHO + tert.mut, data=o, x=T, y=T)), 
           Surv(event.tid, event==1)~1,
           data=o,
           times=c(60,90),
           plots = "calibration",
           summary="risks")
```

Then the two calibration plot

```
plotCalibration(i, 
                cens.method = "local", 
                legend.x=.215,
                legend.y=.225,
                cex=1,
                times=60,
                col=c("#6DBCC3","#8B3A62"),
                ylab="Observed frequency",
                xlab="Predicted risk of recurrence",
                auc.in.legend = TRUE)
```

And

```
plotCalibration(i, 
                cens.method = "local", 
                legend.x=.215,
                legend.y=.225,
                cex=1,
                times=90,
                col=c("#6DBCC3","#8B3A62"),
                ylab="Observed frequency",
                xlab="Predicted risk of recurrence",
                auc.in.legend = TRUE)
```

And then the two `ggplot`

```
ggplot(arrange(o, event.tid) %>% 
         transmute(ID = 1:nrow(o),
                   WHO = WHO,
                   tert.mut = tert.mut) %>%
         left_join(i$Calibration$plotframe, 
                   ., 
                   by="ID") %>%
         select(ID, times, model, risk, WHO, tert.mut) %>%
         pivot_wider(names_from = model, values_from = risk) %>%
         rename(., "woTERT" = "WHO w/o TERT", "wTERT" = "WHO +TERT   ") %>%
         filter(times==60),
       aes(x=woTERT, y=wTERT, shape=WHO, col=tert.mut, fill=tert.mut)) +
  geom_point(size = 7)
```

And

```
ggplot(arrange(o, event.tid) %>% 
         transmute(ID = 1:nrow(o),
                   WHO = WHO,
                   tert.mut = tert.mut) %>%
         left_join(i$Calibration$plotframe, 
                   ., 
                   by="ID") %>%
         select(ID, times, model, risk, WHO, tert.mut) %>%
         pivot_wider(names_from = model, values_from = risk) %>%
         rename(., "woTERT" = "WHO w/o TERT", "wTERT" = "WHO +TERT   ") %>%
         filter(times==90),
       aes(x=woTERT, y=wTERT, shape=WHO, col=tert.mut, fill=tert.mut)) +
  geom_point(size = 7)
```

Attempt #1

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2), mai=c(.65,.75,.3,.3))
# the first two goes well
plotCalibration(i, 
                cens.method = "local", 
                legend.x=.215,
                legend.y=.225,
                cex=1,
                times=60,
                col=c("#6DBCC3","#8B3A62"),
                ylab="Observed frequency",
                xlab="Predicted risk of recurrence",
                auc.in.legend = TRUE)

plotCalibration(i, 
                cens.method = "local", 
                legend.x=.215,
                legend.y=.225,
                cex=1,
                times=90,
                col=c("#6DBCC3","#8B3A62"),
                ylab="Observed frequency",
                xlab="Predicted risk of recurrence",
                auc.in.legend = TRUE)

# here it goes wrong

ggplot(arrange(o, event.tid) %>% 
         transmute(ID = 1:nrow(o),
                   WHO = WHO,
                   tert.mut = tert.mut) %>%
         left_join(i$Calibration$plotframe, 
                   ., 
                   by="ID") %>%
         select(ID, times, model, risk, WHO, tert.mut) %>%
         pivot_wider(names_from = model, values_from = risk) %>%
         rename(., "woTERT" = "WHO w/o TERT", "wTERT" = "WHO +TERT   ") %>%
         filter(times==60),
       aes(x=woTERT, y=wTERT, shape=WHO, col=tert.mut, fill=tert.mut)) +
  geom_point(size = 7) 

ggplot(arrange(o, event.tid) %>% 
         transmute(ID = 1:nrow(o),
                   WHO = WHO,
                   tert.mut = tert.mut) %>%
         left_join(i$Calibration$plotframe, 
                   ., 
                   by="ID") %>%
         select(ID, times, model, risk, WHO, tert.mut) %>%
         pivot_wider(names_from = model, values_from = risk) %>%
         rename(., "woTERT" = "WHO w/o TERT", "wTERT" = "WHO +TERT   ") %>%
         filter(times==90),
       aes(x=woTERT, y=wTERT, shape=WHO, col=tert.mut, fill=tert.mut)) +
  geom_point(size = 7)
```

Attemp #2 was producing a `ggarrange` to combine with `par(mfrow)`, which also failed.

**Expected output**

[image]

Data sample

```
o <- structure(list(event.tid = c(56, 127, 29.6, 18, 13.2, 41, 96, 
146.83, 45.37, 1, 105.29, 55, 13.84, 12, 26, 10.8, 1, 7.2, 22.68, 
59, 16, 8.4, 75.3, 25.7, 13, 21, 19, 22, 48, 93, 26, 72, 73.5, 
125, 31, 63, 2.02, 28.2, 2, 8, 60, 46.7, 53, 4, 85, 12, 75.9, 
1, 5, 2.5), event = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1), WHO = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
2L), .Label = c("WHO-I", "WHO-II", "WHO-III"), class = "factor"), 
    tert.mut = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Have you tried the [`patchwork`](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/assembly.html#adding-non-ggplot-content) package?

Comment: Hi @markus. Yes, but I could not get it to work. You are more than welcome to submit an answer using patchwork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach using `cowplot`.

You can use `as_grob` to convert your `plotCalibration` plots to grobs that can be combined with your 2 ggplots.

You can further customize your calibration plots by adding base R graphics statements to your functions.

With `plot_grid` from `cowplot` you can put your 2x2 plots in arranged form, in this case with 2 rows + 2 columns.

```
library(riskRegression)
library(survival)
library(tidyverse) 
library(cowplot)

i <- Score(list("WHO w/o TERT" = coxph(Surv(event.tid, event==1) ~ WHO, data=o, x=T, y=T), 
                "WHO +TERT   " = coxph(Surv(event.tid, event==1) ~ WHO + tert.mut, data=o, x=T, y=T)), 
           Surv(event.tid, event==1)~1,
           data=o,
           times=c(60,90),
           plots = "calibration",
           summary="risks")

make_pc1 <- function() {
  par(mgp=c(4,1,0), mar=c(5,6,4,2)+0.1, cex.lab=1.4, cex.axis=1.5)
  plotCalibration(i, 
                  cens.method = "local", 
                  legend.x=.215,
                  legend.y=.225,
                  cex=1,
                  times=60,
                  col=c("#6DBCC3","#8B3A62"),
                  ylab="Observed frequency",
                  xlab="Predicted risk of recurrence",
                  auc.in.legend = TRUE)
  mtext("10-year prediction", adj=0.05, line = -1.4, cex=1, font=2)
}

pc1 <- as_grob(make_pc1)

make_pc2 <- function() {
  par(mgp=c(4,1,0), mar=c(5,6,4,2)+0.1, cex.lab=1.4, cex.axis=1.5)
  plotCalibration(i, 
                  cens.method = "local", 
                  legend.x=.215,
                  legend.y=.225,
                  cex=1,
                  times=90,
                  col=c("#6DBCC3","#8B3A62"),
                  ylab="Observed frequency",
                  xlab="Predicted risk of recurrence",
                  auc.in.legend = TRUE)
  mtext("10-year prediction", adj=0.05, line = -1.4, cex=1, font=2)
}

pc2 <- as_grob(make_pc2)

gg1 <- ggplot(arrange(o, event.tid) %>% 
         transmute(ID = 1:nrow(o),
                   WHO = WHO,
                   tert.mut = tert.mut) %>%
         left_join(i$Calibration$plotframe, 
                   ., 
                   by="ID") %>%
         select(ID, times, model, risk, WHO, tert.mut) %>%
         pivot_wider(names_from = model, values_from = risk) %>%
         rename(., "woTERT" = "WHO w/o TERT", "wTERT" = "WHO +TERT   ") %>%
         filter(times==60),
       aes(x=woTERT, y=wTERT, shape=WHO, col=tert.mut, fill=tert.mut)) +
  geom_point(size = 7)

gg2 <- ggplot(arrange(o, event.tid) %>% 
         transmute(ID = 1:nrow(o),
                   WHO = WHO,
                   tert.mut = tert.mut) %>%
         left_join(i$Calibration$plotframe, 
                   ., 
                   by="ID") %>%
         select(ID, times, model, risk, WHO, tert.mut) %>%
         pivot_wider(names_from = model, values_from = risk) %>%
         rename(., "woTERT" = "WHO w/o TERT", "wTERT" = "WHO +TERT   ") %>%
         filter(times==90),
       aes(x=woTERT, y=wTERT, shape=WHO, col=tert.mut, fill=tert.mut)) +
  geom_point(size = 7) 

# Draw all 4 plots
plot_grid(pc1, pc2, gg1, gg2, ncol = 2)
```

**Plot**

[image: cowplot with combined ggplots and calibration plots]

Tweaking the spacing of the calibration plots a bit (e.g., using `title` for the axis labels, and adjusting `mgp` for margin line of axis title), you can do:

```
make_pc1 <- function() {
  par(mar=c(5,6,4,2)+0.1, cex.lab=1.4, cex.axis=1.5)
  plotCalibration(i, 
                  cens.method = "local", 
                  legend.x=.215,
                  legend.y=.225,
                  cex=1,
                  times=60,
                  col=c("#6DBCC3","#8B3A62"),
                  ylab="",
                  xlab="",
                  auc.in.legend = TRUE)
  mtext("10-year prediction", adj=0.05, line = -1.4, cex=1, font=2)
  title(ylab = "Observed frequency", mgp = c(4.5,1,0))
  title(xlab = "Predicted risk of recurrence", mgp = c(2.5,1,0))
}

pc1 <- as_grob(make_pc1)

make_pc2 <- function() {
  par(mar=c(5,6,4,2)+0.1, cex.lab=1.4, cex.axis=1.5)
  plotCalibration(i, 
                  cens.method = "local", 
                  legend.x=.215,
                  legend.y=.225,
                  cex=1,
                  times=90,
                  col=c("#6DBCC3","#8B3A62"),
                  ylab="",
                  xlab="",
                  auc.in.legend = TRUE)
  mtext("10-year prediction", adj=0.05, line = -1.4, cex=1, font=2)
  title(ylab = "Observed frequency", mgp = c(4.5,1,0))
  title(xlab = "Predicted risk of recurrence", mgp = c(2.5,1,0))
}

pc2 <- as_grob(make_pc2)

# Draw all 4 plots
plot_grid(pc1, pc2, gg1, gg2, ncol = 2)
```

**Plot**

[image: modified calibration plots to adjust spacing of axis title]

Comment: Thank you @Ben. That is very nice. I am trying to add `mtext` to `plotCalibration` after `as.grob` - i.e. `pc1 + mtext("10-year prediction", adj=0.05, line = -1.4, cex=1, font=2)`. However, this produces an error: `non-numeric argument to binary operator`. Is it possible to add an `mtext`-object to the `as.grob`-plot?

Comment: - and, usually, I can alter the size of axis text in `plotCalibration` by typing `par(cex.lab=1.4,cex.axis=1.5)`. Can I also modify the axis text size in the `as.grob` by using the `par`-argument or similar? Thank you.

Comment: @cmirian See edited answer. I placed the `plotCalibration` in functions, where you can add whatever you like (e.g., `mtext` and `par`). You may need to add minor adjustments. It also uses `as_grob` (with underscore) from `cowplot` to create grobs. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you @Ben, your answers are always helpful. I will reward you the bounty as soon as it is possible.

Comment: Hi @Ben - sorry, another spin-off question. Is it possible to align the `x-axes` better between the `ggplots` and the `calibrationsplots`? I think the issue can be visualized if you rearrange as `plot_grid(gg1, pc1, gg2, pc2, ncol = 2)` - it is like `pc1` and `pc2` needs more height to match the of the `ggplots`.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but guess you feel the plot height is small with the calibration plots (at least, compared with the other 2 plots). If that is true, you can reduce the margins...for example, to reduce the top margin of the calibration plot, try `par(mar=c(5,6,1,2)+0.1...` (the "1" instead of "4" will make a big difference). You can experiment with `mar` as well as `mgp` to get the look you want. Part of the compromise here is that you have very large axis and tick labels which take space too.

Comment: Or, `mar=c(4,6,1,2)` and reducing the bottom margin looks pretty good too...